# Aligning items in td

Tags: css, alignment, html-table, html-tableextract

How to align the '1' and '2' that shows when a player click on the `<td>` centrally within the element?

[Current version](http://snowsandpatrol.github.io/tic-tac-toe/) can be found here.

Comment: Can you post some code here? Or a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that's very easy to find out by searching... anyways, since you're using table cells, just add the `text-align: center;` rule to the td:

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```